# Bash Script - Need find command to output file paths enclosed in double quotes without line breaks

Tags: linux, bash, unix, alias

I have been using cscope/ctags database. However after sometime I noticed that some files in my **cscope.files** that stores the result of my find command, are broken into two or more lines. This causes them being ignored by cscope/ctags while indexing.

Currently I use it in an alias :

```
alias prp_indx='
    rm cscope.in.out cscope.out cscope.files tags
    find . -name '\''*.[chS]'\'' >> cscope.files
    find . -name '\''*.cpp'\'' >> cscope.files
    find . -name '\''*.hpp'\'' >> cscope.files
    find . -name '\''*.cxx'\'' >> cscope.files
    find . -name '\''*.hxx'\'' >> cscope.files
    cscope -b -q -k; ctags -R
'
```

Please help me with an appropriate command that I can use in my alias/function to achieve the file names with double quotes without paths broken in many lines.

Comment: Why do you have backslashes in your name patterns. Are they really parts of the file names you want to find? To list all C++ source files `find . -name '*.cpp' >> cscope.files` should be enough. Note: prefer a function. Compared to functions aliases mainly have drawbacks.

Comment: If you need files with newlines in their names, you can use the option `-print0` of `find`. It separates the result by the null character instead of a newline. Of course any program processing the result afterwards, must also understand the 0 character as a separator.

Comment: The concrete bug is probably in the crazy quoting you are using around the `-name` arguments. But as already pointed out in Renaud's answer, the straightforward fix is to not use an alias for this (or for anything, ever).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no reason I can think of for `find` to split a file name on several lines, except if the name itself has newline characters in it.

If you have such file names, it is probably better to rename these files as I think `cscope` does not really support file names with newlines in them. At least, I don't think there is a way to list such files in a `cscope.files` file, even with quoting or any kind of escaping (but if you know how to do, please let us know, such that we can adapt what follows accordingly). So, the best you could do is to let `cscope` do the search (`-R`) instead of providing a `cscope.files` file. If you do so `cscope` will indeed find and analyse these files, but then, when interacting with `cscope` you will discover that it gets confused and splits the names anyway...

If you do not have such unusual file names, but there are unwanted newline characters in your `cscope.files` file, there must be something else that tampers with it.

Anyway, prefer a function. Compared to functions, aliases mainly have drawbacks. With a `bash` function:

```sh
prp_indx () {
  rm cscope.in.out cscope.out cscope.files tags
  find . -name '*.[chS]' -o -name '*.[ch]pp' -o -name '*.[ch]xx' > cscope.files
  cscope -b -q -k
  ctags -R "$@"
}
```

Note: if you can have directories with names matching one of the 3 patterns add a `-type` test to exclude directories:

```sh
find . ! -type d \( -name '*.[chS]' -o -name '*.[ch]pp' -o -name '*.[ch]xx' \) > cscope.files
```

If you have unusual file names containing spaces, double-quotes and/or backslashes, you can add a post-processing with, e.g., `sed`:

```
sed -i 's/["\]/\\&/g;s/^\|$/"/g' cscope.files
```

This will add a backslash before any double-quote or backslash, plus double-quote all file names. Add this `sed` command to the function definition, after the `find` command.